# Celery - How to solve PreconditionFailed relating to delivery timeout

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

In my celery cluster I see that some tasks are killed and restarted automatically. This set of celery workers works on long running tasks. This is the error I see logged by celery worker before death

```
"Unrecoverable error: PreconditionFailed(406, 'PRECONDITION_FAILED - delivery acknowledgement on channel 1 timed out. Timeout value used: 1800000 ms. This timeout value can be configured, see consumers doc guide to learn more', (0, 0), '')"
```

How can I solve this issue?

I am using AWS MQ for running a rabbitmq cluster